# how a BIOS program load 2nd stage loader to Internal RAM

Tags: android, linux, boot, lds

I have a conceptual doubt of boot process

known boot sequence

1stage BL > 2ndStage BL > u-boot > kernel

1stage BL : BIOS program, which is meant for minimum initializations and loading the 2ndStage BL to the Internal RAM of the SOC

2ndStage BL : it can be an SPL(android),xloader in some other cases, it would Load the u-boot to RAM after initializing it 
...

here my questions are more on 1ststage loader,which would solve the further doubts

how does it know , where the 2nd stage loader is located which is part of the ROM image?

how does it load the 2ndstage loader on the Internal RAM without initializing the NAND flash memory(i have seen a legacy code where the nand initialization happening inside 2ndstage loader), does the .lds files help while loading the next bootloaders ?

PS: i have only 2ndstage loader source with me but not the BIOS